# mongoose find is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a reports model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    score: Number, 
    notes: String, 
    user: ObjectId, 
    date: Date
}, {timestamps: true})

const Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);

module.exports = Report
```

but when I do a find it says function does not exist:

```
report.find({}, function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs)
  })
```

Comment: You mean `Report` yeah? how you `require` report  model?

Comment: are you requiring mongoose in your file?

Comment: actually now that you mention it i'm using the report as follows which may be my issue: var report = new Report({
    score: req.body.score,
    notes: req.body.notes, 
    user: req.user.id, 
    date: mydate
  });

Comment: Looks like case sensitive issue. Use Report instead of report

Answer (score 0):

Real issue was I thought the model was added but it was not.